# Can I move mount to other mount namespace

Tags: linux, mount, namespace

Question :
Is there any way I could move/copy mount from one namespace to another?

Explanation:
I would like to mount directory which didn't exist when container was created.

1. I am creating container. It gets it own copy of host mount namespace
2. Host creates some `SourceDirectory`
3. Inside host I am bind mounting (with shared option enabled) `SourceDirectory` into `/container_rootfs/tempDirectory`
4. Inside container I would like to read/write file to `/tempDirectory` so it gets to `SourceDirectory`

Step 4. is not working because on step 3 shared bind mount is only shared for the current host mount namespace, and container namespace was already "split" before. I get `/tempDirectory` like I wouldn't done step 3 at all.

If directory existed and the mount was made **before** creating container  (so operation order from numbered list above 2 > 3 > 1 > 4) then everything works just fine as now container has mount namespace copied **after** my additional bind mount was created. And saving to `/tempDirectory` gets transferred to `SourceDirectory`.

So my question is - If there is any way that I could move/copy mount from one namespace (mine host mount namespace) to another (container mount namespace)?

If that is relevant (which I don't think so) I am using crun for containers.

Answer (score 2):

*I'm not aware of a way to retrospectively copy or move an existing mount, but...*

You can execute the `mount --bind` command directly in the container's namespace with [nsenter](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nsenter.1.html).

You must identify the pid (process id) for a process running in the container.  You can use any process in the container as long as you can find it.

- I'll draw your attention to the [`--pid-file` option in crun](https://github.com/containers/crun/blob/master/crun.1.md#exec-options).
- Failing that you may need to use `ps -ef` to search for a process running in the container.  Remember that the container may be in a pid namespace and give different pids inside the container to those of the host.  You need the pid as seen by the host.

Assuming your containerised process has pid `4321` you should be able to mount using:

```
nsenter -mt 4321 mount --bind SourceDirectory /container_rootfs/
```

---

To experiment with `nsenter` I suggest that you try it out with an interactive command line first.  If the pid for your containerised process is `4321` use:

```
nsenter -mt 4321 /bin/bash
```

Remember that there is a difference between a mount namespace and [chroot](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chroot.1.html).  Your containerised processes will have been put in its own mount namespace but will also have been chrooted.  Depending on the way this was done `nsenter` may or may not result in a chroot as well.

---

If you did mount `SourceDirectory` after the container was started, if it's not mounted at all in your container's namespace then it may be possible to mount it in the way you did before...

[From what I read](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=166505) it is allowable to mount a partition twice so if you already executed `mount /dev/sda4` on the host, it should generally be fine to execute `mount /dev/sda4` in the container.  The result will be the same as if you had used a bind mount.

Comment: I already tried with mounting with container pid. The problem with that is when I do it on VM it works, but it looks like some platform fs driver does not support mounting filesystems inside different userns. To do that I would require FS_USERNS_MOUNT. And it is not set. So when I try to mount inside container on my platform I get "Operation not permitted".
About mounting twice I can try doing that.

Comment: @Koczek that's quite an important detail which could have been in your question.  To be clear did that happen when you attempted a bind mount or re-mounting as discussed at the end of my answer?  Could you also identify which drivers don't work?

Comment: This is part of longer problem. I would like to loopmount some file inside container. Container is not privliged. So inside of host I am creating loopmount attach it to file. If I try then to bind mount dev/loop0 to /container_rootfs inside container mount namespace I get "Operation not permitted" (on VM it works fine on my platform it doesn't probably due to this FS_USERNS_MOUNT). If I try to mount this loop device in host to temp and then mount temp inside container it is not "seen" inside container (probably due to the different namespaces)

Comment: File format is Ext4, the host system is sadly Yocto linux to specific platform which I cannot share. For testing I use Vagrant VM. But if you are able to create loopmount inside host (after creation of container), and then make it available inside said container then I would be happy.

Comment: BTW, if you are using crun, --pid-file which you mentioned is generated later in oci life cycle, if you need pid on i.e. CreateRuntime hook you can use json which is provided to container stdin. Just read stdin and inside should be json which contains pid of container.

Comment: @Koczek This is rapidly going beyond the scope of your question.  Let's move the discussion to a room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109738/crum-nsenter

Comment: Yes I agree that this went beyond the scope of this question. This is why I tried to make it so simple and without going into details. About going to discussion room sorry but I have not enough reputation to post there. The long story is I am using C++ to do most of this things, and if it not working then I use linux command line to check if it works there. On my platform I don't even have nsenter command, but I use C++ equivalent of opening new thread and switching mount namespace with unshare+setns.It works but then mounting inside this new namespace is not permitted (on device, on VM works)

Comment: Can you confirm that you are not unsharing the user namespace. It must be only the mount namespace.

Comment: And about FS_USERNS_MOUNT there is page https://kinvolk.io/blog/2018/04/towards-unprivileged-container-builds/ which explains why this flag exist, why mounting from other namespaces could lead to privilege escalation https://www.securityweek.com/canonical-patches-privilege-escalation-vulnerability-ubuntu and probably mounting this way on secure platform is not so good idea. This is why my question was about moving mount to another namespace as this would be more "secure" way of doing things, sadly I also didn't found anything what would point that this is possible. Anyways thanks for help.

Comment: Yes I unshare only "CLONE_NEWNS" not the user namespace. As I said same code works fine on VM, just on my platform it doesn't. This is why I suspect this FS_USERNS_MOUNT flag.

Comment: @Koczek No this is why I'm checking, the flag FS_USERNS_MOUNT refers to the ability for a process in a user namespace to be able to mount.  If you're not entering the user namepsace, it should not apply.